# Array elements cause ] expected error in java

Tags: java, compiler-errors, identifier

I am actively working on a project in my CIS-162 class that requires multiple arrays, however whenever I attempt to compile I am met with a "] expected" error for every element within the array. What did I do wrong?

I've searched for answers across multiple platforms and attempted formatting my arrays to be exactly the same as theirs (format wise) to no avail.

```
private boolean[] bet = new boolean[9];
    bet[0] = false;
    bet[1] = false;
    ...
    bet[8] = false;
```

I should have a 1x9 array of boolean expressions should I not?

Comment: Are you assigning inside a method?

Comment: I second Maroun's question.  It sounds like you're trying to do this outside of the confines of curly brackets {}

Comment: I am assigning as an instance variable

Answer (score 1):

if you are in tha main_class, you sholdn't use private ....;
use directly  boolean[] bet =....

Comment: I am within a separate class, there is no main method currently.

Comment: give the table values at the creation moment like : private boolean[] bet = new boolean[]{true,false .....};
or in the constructor and methods.